# 404 Not Found Error

Tags: migrations

I am trying to transfer my drupal 7 website from share-hosting to VPS. If I do a fresh install of drupal on my VPS everything works fine, but as soon as I upload/migrate my database, the front page works fine, but if I click on any link on my website I keep getting this error. For example if I click on login I get:

> 404 Not Found
>
> The server can not find the requested page:
>
> xx.xxx.xx.xxx/~xxx/user/login (port 80)
>
> Please forward this error screen to XX.XXX.XX.XXX's WebMaster.

Comment: Can you access xx.xxx.xx.xxx/~xxx/?q=user/login ?

Comment: @Molot I cannot, I still get the 404 error. If I click on a link to an article I also get the error. Nothing seems to work except for the front page.

Comment: Couldn't be as simple as missing .htaccess file in the root?

Comment: can you set $base_url in settings.php  to include a directory? $base_url = 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx/~xxx/' ?

Comment: @jdu even after setting the settings.php permission to 0664 I keep getting this "Could not write /home/gamercat/public_html/sites/default/settings.php: Permission denied"

Comment: @clive I see one inside my /public_html folder.

Comment: Did you mean "I do see one...", or is it missing? Regarding permissions, Drupal shouldn't be writing to settings.php after the install process. If you're getting permission errors while installing, make sure the web server can temporarily write to the file. 0664 is fine if www-data (or whatever) is the owner or in the owning group, but otherwise it won't work. See [this article](https://drupal.org/node/244924) for more info

Comment: @clive yes I do see one.

Comment: @jdu I was able to add the line $base_url =  'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~MyCpnelUserName/' using the putty.exe terminal, but after saving, I refreshed my site and I am still getting the 404 error.

Comment: Just to clear things up @clive the permission error was not while installing. I was just trying to edit settings.php to add the line jdu recommended using the cpanel file manager.

Comment: You mention transferring the database, but have you transferred the files?  I have to ask sorry :/

Comment: @Patrick Ryan, yes all the files have been transferred too. Even if I didn't, it should still work. I believe all the pages and text are stored in the database. It's just the images and modules that get stored in the file folders.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a debugging question where only an error message is shown, without additional information as to what has already been tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer over at StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280015/apache-404-error-drupal

All I had to do was add `RewriteBase /~YourCpanelUserNameGoesHere` into the .htacess file